# Como comparar valor de variável com operador de incremento?

Tags: php

**Segue a função:**

```
$conteudo = $textodobanco;
function addBanner($i) {
    static $conta1 = 0;
    $retorno = $i[0];
    if (++$conta1 == 5) {
        $retorno .= '<b>BANNER 1</b>';
    }
    return $retorno;
}

$txt = preg_replace_callback('#(<br />)#', 'addBanner', $conteudo);
```

A função acima funciona perfeitamente, porém, preciso que ao invés de utilizar o número **5** expresso na comparação, que ele seja substituído por uma variável, para assim dinamizar o sistema que estou desenvolvendo.

Porém, todas as tentativas como por exemplo abaixo em substituir o número **5** por uma variável não funcionou, ou seja, a função não retorna resultado algum.

Substituição pela variável, porém, sem sucesso

```
function addBanner($i) {
    static $conta1 = 0;
    $retorno = $i[0];
    if (++$conta1 == $numerovar) {
        $retorno .= '<b>BANNER 1</b>';
    }
    return $retorno;
}
```

Comment: @rray como mostrei no primeiro exemplo, o número 5 está expresso. Preciso colocar uma variável no lugar dele. $i é outra coisa.

Comment: Na função informe dois parâmetros, depois do `$i` pode chamar um `$limite` pode definir uma valor padrão para ele. ex: `function addBanner($i, $limite=3)`

Comment: @Gladison a variável que irá utilizar para realizar a comparação está gravado no banco?? já verificou o que está sendo retornado?

Comment: @Oliveira Sim, está vindo do banco de dados e verifiquei o valor retornado, no caso, 5. Porém, esta função não funciona se eu substituir o número cinco pela variável. Não sei porque isso acontece.

Comment: O enunciado não tem relação com o problema. A comparação do seu código está correta, o que não está é a falta de uma passagem ou criação da variável (você compara com `$numerovar` mas não passa essa variável para a função de nenhuma forma). Seria importante [edit] reduzir o código a um [mcve] se quiser mais detalhes. A resposta abaixo explica as soluções ideais (independente do valor vir do DB ou não, o caminho é o mesmo). - Fundamental estudar o manual do PHP em relação ao [escopo das variáveis](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer a comparação com uma variável primeiro você precisa ou cria-la ou passar ela como Parâmetro...

Segue um exemplo passando ela como *Parâmetro*:

```
function addBanner($i, $numerovar)
{
   static $conta1 = 0;
   $retorno = $i[0];
   if(++$conta1 == $numerovar)
   {
      $retorno .= '<b>BANNER 1</b>';
   }
   return $retorno;
}
```

Segue um exemplo *Criando* ela:

```
function addBanner($i)
{
   static $conta1 = 0;
   $retorno = $i[0];
   $numerovar = 10;
   if(++$conta1 == $numerovar)
   {
      $retorno .= '<b>BANNER 1</b>';
   }
   return $retorno;
}
```

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou. A minha variável `$numerovar` recebe um número do banco de dados. Não posso colocar na função um número pré-definido.

Comment: No seu primeiro exemplo eu atribuí a variável `$num` um valor do banco e nada.

Comment: Conseguindo alguma coisa?

Comment: Caro Marccus a sua ideia esta quase certa, se eu entendi direito, mas o código do AP é com `preg_replace_callback`, da forma que esta não funciona, uma sugestão seria usar uma função anonima, exemplo: https://gist.github.com/brcontainer/f85ff8dc606840d77803b04cabc2b24e (cc @Gladison veja se consegue entender) (código atualizado no gist, faltava um detalhe)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Perfeito, funcionou!!! Muito obrigado.